# Name mangling problems when using GNU linker to link to VC++ compiled library

Tags: c++, linker, eclipse-cdt, visual-c++

In asking this question, I'm looking for either better understanding of the situation or preferably a solution.

I'm created C++ code and I would like to be able to use the Eclipse CDT IDE rather than Visual Studios, (my workplace is more Eclipse friendly).  This implies that, practically speaking, I must use the GNU tool chain to compile my code.  For the project at hand, I must link to a library called HyDE.lib that was compiled with the Visual Studios compiler.  Of course, the problem that I run into is that the GNU linker can't find the appropriate symbols in HyDE because (I presume) both compilers use different name mangling schemes.

So how do I get around this?

Current thoughts:

- The most obvious thing would be to recompile HyDE.lib with the GNU tool chain.  This is proving to be more complicated than perhaps it's worth.  However there is one avenue that I haven't investigated here.  We have a cmake file that supposedly can build to unix... is there some way to have cmake instead use Cygwin GNU?  I really know nothing about cmake (and very little about make), so a reference to good information would be nice.
- I could connect Eclipse CDT to the Window compiler tools.  Yes, but best I can tell this is not easy, and I would potentially lose debugging and maybe even code completion.  Then there is Eclipse Wascana, but I read a recent blog that indicated that the Wascana community is waining.
- Is there any sort of library demangler-remangler?  I imagine a program that I would give a Windows compiled library too, and the program would pick out the symbols, demangle them, and then create a library that had the same symbols, but mangled in the GNU way.  At this point I'm making stuff up, so maybe someone could help me better understand name mangling here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you place most of the code in HyDE.lib with `extern "C"` blocks, then your best bet is to recompile it with G++. Even if you do place it in `extern "C"` blocks, I would still reccomend compiling it with G++ as it usually (but not always) has better support for standards than MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, complete the compilation of the library into a .dll file and use that. Just make sure to put entry points in `extern "C"` blocks.

Comment: Blindy, you don't happen to be blind do you?  If so I might have questions about your programming setup?

Comment: No, I'm not blind, my "handle" is a long story <.<